# How can we make the user to edit and save the details in the profile page in vue.js + Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I wanted user to update details(first name, last name) and save them. Here I have access the given details only. After updating how can I save them again to the same variables?

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog">
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <span class="headline">Edit User</span>
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-text>
      <v-container grid-list-md>
        <v-layout wrap>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
            <v-text-field v-model="user.firstName" label="First Name"></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>

          <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
            <v-text-field v-model="user.lastName" label="Last Name"></v-text-field>
          </v-flex>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>

            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat>Cancel</v-btn>

            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat>Save</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to send a http request to backend and save data using the response.
Refer this tutorial for more details.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for basic things.
1. Create Laravel controller 
2. Call api via your Vue component using `axios` or other http client

https://medium.com/@mscherrenberg/laravel-5-6-vue-js-simple-form-submission-using-components-92b6d5fd4434 You can also follow this tutorial to get better understanding